# mac os x connect active directory

Tags: windows, macos, active-directory, fileserver

we have a design office full of macs, but we want to achieve a robust user arquitecture, we're thinking in using windows server active directory for this task.

Is it possible to connect macosx machines to a windows server domain and user its login features and group features and permissions for file server?

Is it an easy task?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to have client machines connect to an Active Directory server. Go to System Preferences » Users and groups and select Login. At the bottom of that preference pane where is an option to connect to a directory server.

No idea how easy it will be to setup. I'm on OS X Lion by the way.